# how do you generate random numbers from a bimodal Gaussian Probability Density Function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, gaussian

How do you generate numbers from a bimodal Gaussian PDF in MATLAB?

For a unimodal symmetric Gaussian PDF it is really easy:

```
x=randn(1000,1);
```

But now I want to draw 1000 numbers from a Gaussian PDF that has two peaks (or two means).  How do I do this?

Comment: The Gaussian is always unimodal. Do you mean a mixture of Gaussians? You can draw samples `x1` from one of the mixture components, and another set of samples `x2` from the second one. Then combine to get a sample from the mixture. The number of draws from each is determined by their weight in the mixture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the bimodal Normal (Gaussian) distribution by combining two Normal distributions with different mean and standard deviation (as explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688563/how-do-you-generate-random-numbers-from-a-bimodal-gaussian-probability-density-f#comment82338221_47688563)).

In MATLAB you can do this in several ways:

First, we need to specify the mean (`mu`) and standard deviation (`sigma`) that characterize our Normal distributions, usually noted as `N(mu, sigma)`.

Normal distribution a: `N(-1, 0.5)`

```
mu_a = -1;      % Mean (a).
sigma_a = 0.5;  % Standard deviation (a).
```

Normal distribution b: `N(2, 1)`

```
mu_b = 2;       % Mean (b).
sigma_b = 1;    % Standard deviation (b).
```

Finally, let's define the size of our random vectors:

```
sz = [1e4, 1];  % Size vector.
```

Now let's generate the bimodal random values by concatenating two vectors of Normally distributed random numbers:

**OPTION 1:** using [`randn`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html)

```
x_1 = [sigma_a*randn(sz) + mu_a, sigma_b*randn(sz) + mu_b];
```

**OPTION 2:** using [`normrnd`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html)

```
x_2 = [normrnd(mu_a, sigma_a, sz), normrnd(mu_b, sigma_b, sz)];
```

**OPTION 3:** using [`random`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/random.html)

```
x_3 = [random('Normal', mu_a, sigma_a, sz), random('Normal', mu_b, sigma_b, sz)];
```

Let's visualize the results:

```
subplot(1, 3, 1); histogram(x_1);
subplot(1, 3, 2); histogram(x_2);
subplot(1, 3, 3); histogram(x_3);
```

[image: bimodal normal distributions]

Answer (score 3):

I propose you an alternative that uses [gmdistribution](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.html):

```
% Means (X1 -> -0.5 and X2 -> 1.2)
m = [-0.5; 1.2];

% Standard Deviations (X1 -> 2.1 and X2 -> 1.3)
s = cat(3,2.1,1.3);

% Weights (X1 and X2 Equally Weighted 0.5)
w = ones(1,2) / 2;

% Create the Gaussian Mixture Model...
gmd = gmdistribution(m,s,w);

% Draw 1000 random numbers from it...
x = random(gmd,1000);

% Plot a histogram...
histogram(x,100);
```

Comment: Nice one Tommaso! This should be the accepted answer since the `gmdistribution` function is the right tool for the job.